# BarChartModel how to adjust only the width of the bars without changing the entire chart

Tags: css, primefaces, chart.js

**I'm having trouble changing just the width of the bars. Right now, the chart is working fine, but I need to adjust only the width of the bars without changing the entire chart. How can I do that?
Please let me know how to do that. bellow is my current code.**

java code:

```
    private void createTaxaRetornoEventosBarModel(){

        this.taxaRetornoEventosBarModel = new BarChartModel();
        ChartData data = new ChartData();
        
        BarChartDataSet barDataSet = new BarChartDataSet();
        barDataSet.setLabel("My First Dataset");
        
        List<Number> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add(65);
        values.add(59);
        values.add(80);
        values.add(81);
        values.add(56);
        values.add(55);
        values.add(40);
        barDataSet.setData(values);
        
        List<String> bgColor = new ArrayList<>();
        bgColor.add("rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)");
        bgColor.add("rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)");
        bgColor.add("rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)");
        bgColor.add("rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)");
        bgColor.add("rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)");
        bgColor.add("rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)");
        bgColor.add("rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)");
        barDataSet.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
        
        List<String> borderColor = new ArrayList<>();
        borderColor.add("rgb(255, 99, 132)");
        borderColor.add("rgb(255, 159, 64)");
        borderColor.add("rgb(255, 205, 86)");
        borderColor.add("rgb(75, 192, 192)");
        borderColor.add("rgb(54, 162, 235)");
        borderColor.add("rgb(153, 102, 255)");
        borderColor.add("rgb(201, 203, 207)");
        barDataSet.setBorderColor(borderColor);
        barDataSet.setBorderWidth(1);
        
        data.addChartDataSet(barDataSet);
        
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
        labels.add("January");
        labels.add("February");
        labels.add("March");
        labels.add("April");
        labels.add("May");
        labels.add("June");
        labels.add("July");
        data.setLabels(labels);

        this.taxaRetornoEventosBarModel.setData(data);
        
        BarChartOptions options = new BarChartOptions();
        CartesianScales cScales = new CartesianScales();
        CartesianLinearAxes linearAxes = new CartesianLinearAxes();
        CartesianLinearTicks ticks = new CartesianLinearTicks();
        ticks.setBeginAtZero(true);
        linearAxes.setTicks(ticks);
        cScales.addYAxesData(linearAxes);
        options.setScales(cScales);
        
        Title title = new Title();
        title.setDisplay(true);
        title.setText("Bar Chart");
        options.setTitle(title);

        Legend legend = new Legend();
        legend.setDisplay(false);
        legend.setPosition("top");
        LegendLabel legendLabels = new LegendLabel();
        legendLabels.setFontStyle("bold");
        legendLabels.setFontColor("#2980B9");
        legendLabels.setFontSize(24);
        legend.setLabels(legendLabels);
        options.setLegend(legend);

        this.taxaRetornoEventosBarModel.setOptions(options);
   }
```

xhtml and CSS, please if you know how, tell me.:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


    <div class="mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center" style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto;">
        <div style="width: max-content;">
            <p:barChart model="#{MB.taxaRetornoEventosBarModel}" style="height: 400px; width: 1100px;"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</ui:composition>
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear in what context you want to change the width of the bars, but, in general, once you have a `BarChartOptions options`, you have to call `options.setBarPercentage`, e.g., `options.setBarPercentage(0.5)` (the default is 0.9). You may want to explore `options.setCategoryPercentage` which is useful if you have more than one dataset, and `options.setBarThickness` which allows you to set the bar width in pixels. Check the [`BarChartOptions`](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/8.0/index.html?org/primefaces/model/charts/bar/BarChartOptions.html) class reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use extender! Since, similar to Calendar module, this widget is based on external library, Chart.js

Easy start - check on the bottom of this list:
https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/13_0_0/#/components/charts?id=barchart

Then, clear all other extender atributes (except these you use already) and add "barThickness" attribute. Play with it, here is guide, just couple lines of text:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barthickness